# PHP Shell_exec and sudo commands for SELinux administration

Tags: php, selinux

I am trying to build a very simple administration tool for some website in a development environment with SELinux

I need to run chcon with shell_exec or something that will have the same effect.  The output states the security context has changed, but a "ls -lZ" shows that the security context has not changed.

```
$temp =  "chcon -v -R -t httpd_sys_content_t " . $_POST['site'];
echo $temp;
$test = shell_exec($temp);
echo $test;
```

I have added the apache user to the sudoer list for chcon

```
apache  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chcon
```

and changed to code to this

```
$temp =  "sudo -u apache chcon -v -R -t httpd_sys_content_t " . $_POST['site'];
echo $temp;
$test = shell_exec($temp);
echo $test;
```

now I receive no out put

I have also created bash script with the following as a work around.  The bash script worked from console but when ran from php it doesn't do anything

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u apache chcon -v -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t $1
```

Altered code

```
$temp = '/path/to/script/test.sh ' . $_POST['site'];
echo $temp . "<br />";
$test = shell_exec($temp);
echo $test;
```

Answer (score 2):

After digging around and doing some testing I have found my answers.

Here is some php that will help generate errors so you can chase down fixes

```
$temp = 'sudo mkdir test 2>&1';
echo $temp . "<br />";
$test = shell_exec($temp);
echo $test;
```

requiretty in sudoers need to be commented out

```
#Defaults   requiretty
```

and an auit2allow policy need to be put in to place.

If audit2allow is not currently installed.

```
 yum install policycoreutils-python
```

the following will create the policy that needs to be in place to execute your commands that are allowed in the sudoers list without a password

```
setenforce 0
echo "" > /var/log/audit/audit.log
/etc/init.d/auditd restart
<execute your php code that requires sudo>
setenforce 1
cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M httpd_sudo
semodule -i httpd_sudo.pp
```

Comment: Good resolution, I working on SELinux hours, but did not know the the sudoers needs modify.